# What is a good setup for editing PHP in Emacs?

Tags: php, emacs, editor, autocomplete

I'm going to be doing some PHP editing for my job this summer, and am looking for an effective Emacs setup for editing it. I'm already heavily invested in Emacs, so switching to another editor is not worthwhile.

Right now, I have [nXhtml-mode](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html), which provides a PHP mode with syntax highlighting (there are at least three different ones in the wild) as well as MuMaMo for editing PHP embedded in HTML. I just started using [Auto-Complete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) and [Anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) for programming and general Emacs stuff, respectively.

What I'm really looking for is an effective way to get Emacs to really understand the project, beyond just highlighting. [Etags](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags) looks like a good option, but it looks like the process for generating new tags is kind of arduous and manual (or at least not invisible). The nice thing about Etags is that they integrate well with Anything and Auto-Complete. Other potential options are [gtags](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuGlobal) (though I'm hesitant to install non-elisp files, just for the complexity), [vtags](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/VTags), or [Semantic](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SemanticBovinator), which I've messed with before and seems complicated to set up, plus it doesn't look like it has support for PHP.

Another option is [Imenu](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImenuMode), but it only works for the current buffer, and I would like to be able to jump to function definitions in other files (preferably using Anything for completion of the name).

The projects I will be working on are not that big (about 30,000 lines total), so the overhead of Etags probably won't be that big of an issue, but I'd rather not use it if there is a better solution.

So what is your preferred PHP editing system?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In addition to features you are already familiar with, I suggest you the followings.

#### ETags

I do not use ETags, but there is a question already on SO *[How to programmatically create/update a TAGS file with emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548414/how-to-programmatically-create-update-a-tags-file-with-emacs)*. No good answer was posted, though, but it may be a good entry point to get an idea.

#### Debugging

[Flymake](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake) is a mode to get on the fly syntax checking. It has support for PHP as well. It hints at syntax errors immediately as you type. The Flymake version shipped with Emacs 23 contains PHP support. If you have previous version, check Sacha Chua's post on *[Emacs and PHP: On-the-fly syntax checking with Flymake](http://sachachua.com/wp/2008/07/31/emacs-and-php-on-the-fly-syntax-checking-with-flymake/)*.

Another useful package is [Geben](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/) that allows you to debug your scripts interactively. For PHP, you can use XDebug. There is a detailed tutorial on how to do that, see *[Debug php in emacs with geben](http://blog.local.ch/archive/2008/08/08/debug-php-in-emacs-with-geben.html)*.

#### Documentation lookup

PHP Mode has a nice feature to lookup the function's definition in PHP's manual in your web browser (`M-x php-search-documentation` or `C-c C-f`). You can combine it with [Emacs-W3M](http://emacs-w3m.namazu.org/) to get the relevant manual page without leaving Emacs.

Comment: +1 for the php-search-documentation feature I had no idea about.

Comment: The link to debugging with Emacs/geben is broken ☹

Comment: [Internet archive of now gone link](https://web.archive.org/web/20131118131254/http://blog.local.ch/en/2008/08/08/debug-php-in-emacs-with-geben/).

Answer (score 5):

web-model.el (available on [web-mode.org](http://web-mode.org)) handles pretty well php blocks embedded in an html document. This major mode will also highlight js and css parts.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to ETags, consider GNU Global, aka "GTags".  Global is a lot smarter about finding tags tables, and is fairly fast to update.  Emacs-fu has a nice post about [doing this on-the-fly](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/01/navigating-through-source-code-using.html).

BTW, if you're using the Windows port of GNU Global with a Windows Emacs build, use the DJGPP ("DOS") version.  The MinGW ("Win32") build seems to have a problem with path names.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer given on May 28 '09, I think I can add some packages to it which enhanced my PHP experience on Emacs.

### Auto-completion

[ac-php](https://github.com/xcwen/ac-php) is in my opinion a good additions to Etags. All references to a tag will  be found with etags, but the definition with ac-php. ac-php is also configurable to which directories should be included. For example, while developing a wordpress plugin, you can add a reference to the directory containing the wordpress files in `.ac-php-conf.json` (which resides in the project root) and it will auto-complete, jump to reference, etc. This package supports `company-mode` and `auto-complete`.

Here's an example configuration of ac-php:

```
(use-package ac-php
  :ensure t
  :bind (:map
         php-mode-map
         ("M-+" . ac-php-find-symbol-at-point)
         ("M-]" . ac-php-location-stack-back)
         ("<menu> r" . ac-php-remake-tags)
         ("<menu> R" . ac-php-remake-tags-all)))
```

Another option would be to use [phpactor](https://phpactor.readthedocs.io/en/master/), but the Emacs interface is at the time of writing still in alpha stage, with which I also hardly have any experience - except for the constructor completion, which works pretty well.

### Error checking

In addition to syntax errors, Flycheck supports [phpMessDetector](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd) and [phpCodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) out of the box. This enables you to have more enhanced notice/warning/error reporting based on supported coding standard and best practices.

Another package I like for static analysis is [PHPStan Emacs interface](https://github.com/emacs-php/phpstan.el), which reports potential errors in your code (including incorrect type hints).

#### Additional formatting

I also use [phpcbf](https://github.com/nishimaki10/emacs-phpcbf) (which apparantly is archived). This package formats the buffer into the wanted coding standard.

### Semantic

For anyone in the dark, Semantic is a built-in Emacs package and provides IDE like features. Here's an example how to include semantic for php-mode:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (require 'semantic/symref/grep)
                           (add-to-list 'semantic-symref-filepattern-alist '(php-mode "*.php" "*.inc"))
                           (semantic-mode)))
```

#### Imenu

For including imenu jumping to definitions, another example configuration:

This is the sidebar for jumping to **in-file** methods and functions.

```
(use-package imenu-list
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq imenu-list-focus-after-activation t)
  :bind (:map php-map
         ("<menu> \\" . imenu-list-smart-toggle)))
```

Example config for helm support in jumping to definitions **in all project files**:

```
(use-package imenu-anywhere
  :ensure t
  :after helm
  :bind (:map php-map
         ("<menu> |" . helm-imenu-anywhere)))
```

### Additional debugging

Besides geben, I like to use [psysh](https://github.com/emacs-php/psysh.el), which by dropping in `eval(\Psy\sh());` gives a repl on that line of code and gives access to all definitions and whatever else one would have access to (ofcourse, after requiring it in composer).

### More generally handy packages

#### Snippets

Maybe a bit obvious for everyone already experienced with Emacs, but [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) is also very handy for writing your own templates. There are also packages that include a lot of predefined templates for all sorts of languages, but I write my own to keep Emacs a little less bloated than my set-up already is, it also helps me remember them more easily.

#### Project management

Excuse the obviousness again, but Projectile is also a very good package which by default includes git support for scoping the project.

#### Offline documentation

If you use Zeal for offline documentation browsing, there's also `zeal-at-point`. Example configuration, if you use, lets say: PHP, CodeIgniter and WordPress:

```
(use-package zeal-at-point
  :ensure t
  :bind (("<menu> z" . zeal-at-point))
  :config
  (add-to-list 'zeal-at-point-mode-alist '(php-mode . ("codeigniter" "wordpress" "php"))))
```