# geben and xdebug on emacs

Tags: java, php, linux, emacs

I have installed [geben](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/) and [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to debug PHP code but i don't know how to use them with emacs .
I have used `M-x geben` but i got this "waiting for debug server to connect at port 900"

So how do I use geben to debug php code and plz if there is any tutorial just give the link thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As written on [What is a good setup for editing PHP in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912671/what-is-a-good-setup-for-editing-php-in-emacs), see  http://blog.local.ch/archive/2008/08/08/debug-php-in-emacs-with-geben.html ([Internet Archive copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20131118131254/http://blog.local.ch/en/2008/08/08/debug-php-in-emacs-with-geben/)) for a tutorial.

Comment: [Internet Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20131118131254/http://blog.local.ch/en/2008/08/08/debug-php-in-emacs-with-geben/)

Answer (score 1):

After you have installed and configured xdebug in php.ini and restarted your apache server if you have set xdebug to not start by default.

```
http://url?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1
```